# Matching values from multiple txt files in Python

Tags: python, text, match, extract

I have 2 txt files and I need to grab a value from fileA, match it with fileB and print the result.

fileA contains userID, artistID and how many times artistID has been played.
fileB contains artistID and the name of the artist.

I need to write a function that will tell me how many times a certain user has played an artist. I need to print the name of the artist and the number of times. I got the pseudocode done but having trouble moving forward.

```
def printListenersTimesPlayed(userID)
    find all artists and number of time they've been played from fileA
    find the name of the artist from fileB
    print list of artists and times that the user (userID) has played
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching the full code along with my sample file for your reference. Please check whether it solves your problem or not.

`import sys`

`import csv`

`mapFileA=sys.argv[1]`

`mapFileB=sys.argv[2]`

`Artist_dict ={}`

`data_dict ={}`

`with open(mapFileB,'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for l in data:
        Artist_dict[l[0]]=l[1]`

`with open(mapFileA,'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for l in data:
        if(l[1] in Artist_dict):
            data_dict[l[0]]=(Artist_dict[l[1]],l[2])`

`## function declaration 
def findartist(userId):
    if (userId in data_dict):
        artist,times=data_dict[userId]
        print("user "+userId+" played artist "+artist+" "+times+"times")`

`## function call
findartist("100A")`

sample files :
file A - it contains user_id,Artist_Id,no. of times user played artist

`100A,AAA,10
100B,BBB,3
100C,CCC,50
100D,DDD,7`

file B: It has Artist_id, Artist_Name

`AAA,ArtistA
BBB,ArtistB
CCC,ArtistC
DDD,ArtistD`

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but I am not allowed to use sys or csv. only numpy :/